# Is there anyway to play MP4, AVI, MKV in Firefox browser without downloading?

Tags: firefox, video, video-streaming

Firefox browser can handle and stream FLV files with help of Adobe Flash Player, it is well known to us.

But can we play MP4, AVI, MKV file in Firefox without downloading?

Comment: I know its not a media player.But it streams flv videos from youtube and other sites.So I wanted to know is there anyway to play other kind of media files,not from my HDD but streaming from website.

Answer (score 3):

A bit deeper explanation to answer above:

Yes, it's possible to play videos (mkv, mp4, ogg, etc) with the modern browser without a plugin. You can do that by using "video" tag.

Support matrix for the different browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/video);
on the sub-feature tab are listed supported video/audio formats and their support matrix across the browsers.

Summary:

You can play video/audio files, but they should be encoded in supported by browser format.

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple HTML5 file with a `[video]` tag to test MP4, M4V, and MKV container formats.

The video stream was H.264 and the audio stream was AAC in all 3 cases.

- Firefox 61.0.1 (Windows) will play MP4 and M4V, but *not* MKV
- Firefox 53.0.3 (Linux) will play MP4 and M4V, but *not* MKV

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to play MP4 and possibly MKV using the HTML [`<video>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) element, although you haven't explained your setup, so it's hard to say whether this will work for you.

As an example, you can simply drag an MP4 video into a Firefox tab, and it will play (assuming H.264 video and AAC audio, anyway). I don't have an MKV file handy at the moment, but that might work too (on Chrome, I've successfully played both MP4 and MKV by dragging the file into a tab). I'm not sure any browser vendor is officially supporting the MKV container, though; it may only work as a by-product of supporting WebM.

I don't think AVI is generally considered to have much of a future, so I doubt anyone will be adding support for that container format.